# Laravel auth, disable password

Tags: php, laravel

I am trying to disable the password verification system from my laravel website. I want to login my users using only their first name and last name. Form wise and register wise and database wise, password field has been removed completely. But in login controller, i am having some issues, it does not seem to work. Here is my code:

```
public function login(Request $request)
{
  $first_name = $request->first_name;
  $last_name = $request->last_name;

  $user = User::where(['first_name' => $first_name, 'last_name' => $last_name])->first();

  if (!$user) {
    return redirect()->back()->withInput($request->only('first_name', 'last_name'))->withErrors([
        'first_name' => 'We could not find you in our database, if you think this is a mistake kindly contact the site administrators',
    ]);
  }

  Auth::login($user);
  return redirecte('/');

}
```

in the above code, i am getting the error message

> We could not find you in our database, if you think this is a mistake kindly contact the site administrators

regardless of what info (true of false) i insert in my form.

Comment: Did you try to change `if (!$user)` with `if (empty($user))`. That's what I usually do for check if the model is empty

Comment: If you get that error means according to your code, Their is no such user exists with that first_name and last_name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes thank you @laravel levaral for answering, but i found out the problem.
I am going to quote a user from laracasts

> If you're going to group multiple where clauses into a single where(), each needs to be it's own array, within an array. You're sending a single array. You're also using =>, which isn't correct. The parameters for each where statement are separated by commas.

so for whoever wants to see the new working code:

```
public function login(Request $request)
{
  $first_name = $request->first_name;
  $last_name = $request->last_name;

  $user = User::where('first_name', $first_name)
  ->where('last_name', $last_name)
  ->first();

  if (!$user) {
    return redirect()->back()->withInput($request->only('first_name', 'last_name'))->withErrors([
        'first_name' => 'We could not find you in our database, if you think this is a mistake kindly contact the site administrators',
    ]);
  }

  Auth::login($user);
  return redirect('/');

}
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you have to check either the `first_name`and `last_name` matches the database.

```
$user = User::where(['first_name' => $first_name, 'last_name' => $last_name])->first()
```

You have a problem in above lines.

```
public function login(Request $request)
{
  $first_name = $request->first_name;
  $last_name = $request->last_name;

  $user = User::where(['first_name' => $first_name, 'last_name' => $last_name])->first();

  if (!$user) {
    return redirect()->back()->withInput($request->only('first_name', 'last_name'))->withErrors([
        'first_name' => 'We could not find you in our database, if you think this is a mistake kindly contact the site administrators',
    ]);
  }

  Auth::loginUsingId($user->id);
  return redirecte('/');

}
```

Comment: first can you explain what you did? second, it did not work.

Comment: The diff is `Auth::loginUsingId($user->id);`. But since the error message is generated before even reaching this line, this does not solve it.